# Is it possible to use an effect with Triggered as an Instant effect?

Tags: mutants-and-masterminds-3e

The text for the [Triggered](https://www.d20herosrd.com/6-powers/modifiers/) Flat Extra (my emphasis):

> You **can** “set” an instant duration effect with this modifier to activate under particular circumstances, such as in response to a particular danger, after a set amount of time, in response to a particular event, and so forth—chosen when you apply the modifier. Once chosen, the trigger cannot be changed.

Does this mean that, if the descriptor fits, you can use it without the Trigger, much like how you can choose whether to Ricochet (a Flat Extra with similar phrasing) an attack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hero's Handbook** page 135 (emphasis added):

> Unless its description specifies otherwise, a modifier is a permanent change in how the effect works. That is, you do not have the option of using the modifier or not, **it always applies**. For different versions of an effect with different modifiers—such as a regular Damage effect and one with the Area modifier—see the Alternate Effect modifier.

Which brings us back to Triggered for your question. Does the description of **Triggered** "specify otherwise"?

> You can “set” an instant duration effect with this modifier to activate under particular circumstances, such as in response to a particular danger, after a set amount of time, in response to a particular event, and so forth—chosen when you apply the modifier. Once chosen, the trigger cannot be changed.

As you note, it does specify otherwise. Unless the GM disagrees with that reading, using Triggered is *optional* and you can simply use the power normally.