# If I have an Extended Teleport effect, can it be triggered when I get knocked out?

Tags: mutants-and-masterminds-3e, mutants-and-masterminds

This is the power I bought for my character

> Triggered(1) Extended Teleport 10
>   Trigger: When Artifice is knocked out, he teleports away from enemies to a teleport beacon he's set up.

Teleport says this:

> You can move instantly from place to place without crossing the distance in between. You can teleport yourself and
>   up to 50 lbs. (mass rank 0) of additional mass a distance
>   rank equal to your effect rank as a move action. Unwilling
>   passengers get a Dodge resistance check to avoid being
>   taken along.

Extended says this:

> Extended: You can take two move actions to make an extended teleport with a distance rank equal to your effect
>   rank +8. You are dazed and vulnerable for one round after
>   an extended teleport. +1 cost per rank.

Triggered says this:

> You can “set” an instant duration effect with this modifier
>   to activate under particular circumstances, such as in response to a particular danger, after a set amount of time,
>   in response to a particular event, and so forth—chosen
>   when you apply the modifier. Once chosen, the trigger
>   cannot be changed.
>   The circumstances must be detectable by your senses.
>   You can acquire Senses Limited and Linked to Triggered
>   effects, if desired. Setting the effect requires the same action as using it normally.

Using this, is it possible to use the Triggered modifier to teleport me away when my character is knocked out, and can I use the Extended modifier with it as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first blush, this seems alright. As per [Is it possible to use an effect with Triggered as an Instant effect?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/141272/is-it-possible-to-use-an-effect-with-triggered-as-an-instant-effect?rq=1), there's nothing explicitly keeping you from using the Teleport without setting up the Triggered effect. And nothing in the description of Triggered says that you can't make it a double-action ("paid" at the time of setting it). One minor technical point is that you have to be able to sense the condition, which may depend on whether your GM considers you sensate enough at the time of being rendered unconscious to realize you're unconsciousness (and an Insidious attack might not trigger it at all if you don't make your Perception check). Another is that a Triggered effect creates something that can be detected and disarmed with reasonable skill checks, which may or may not fit with your concept.

### The big question is, what does your GM say?

*Mutants and Masterminds* is a system that lets you do just about anything, including potentially game-breaking builds, while remaining technically within the rules. In general, the system gets balanced by the GM knowing when to say No to a concept, even if they've approved it before.